# How to run instrumentation tests after converting app to instant app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

After converting and trying to run my instrumentation tests. I get the following error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedServertestDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at:
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out moving the ui tests to the module that builds the apk fixed this problem.

Comment: You sir are a legend